# Ionic framework ionSlideBox : how to change slide after button ng-click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

i implemented ionic SlideBox component:

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlideBox/

I would like to make slide (forward or backward) after click on button (not only after swipe gesture) is it possible and how can i do it please?

Many thanks for any example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you read the page you included, you see a reference to [`$ionicSlideBoxDelegate`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/nightly/api/service/$ionicSlideBoxDelegate/).
With that delegate you can do:

```
<button ng-click="slidePrevious()">Previous</button>
<button ng-click="slideNext()">Next</button>
```

controller:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$ionicSlideBoxDelegate', function($scope, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate) {

    $scope.slidePrevious = function() {

        $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.previous();
    }

    $scope.slideNext = function() {

        $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.next();
    }
});
```

Checkout [this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EaWVZV) with a working example.